# how do i integrate custom report into report portal

Tags: reportportal

I have a custom python comparator report that basically compares 100's of api request/responses. How do i integrate with report portal.

One more request how to wrap cuRL commands in a test framework that can be called by reportportal

Answer (score 0):

The following sources might be useful for you:
ReportPortal API: https://YOUR_SERVER_NAME/ui/#api
The URL above will open Swagger autogenerated API page that is capable to generate curl commands. See the example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgd18.png)

Some details regarding existing reportportal agent and protocol implementation can be found here:
https://reportportal.io/docs/Log-Data-in